# Combination of starts with and contains

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a search in my app. I had originally used `.Contains` but then realized that if I user entered, say, "s" it would return anything that had an "s" in it. So then I switched to `.StartsWith` but then the problem is that if I have "Bottle of Water" and search for "Water" it won't show. Is there a way I could write a regex that would get "Bottle of water" if I typed any of the following: "Bottle", "Bottle of", "of water", "water" "Bottle of water", "of"?

I had thought of perhaps doing an initial search with starts with, then splitting the string and searching it and merging those to and using `.Distinct` to get unique records,  but I think if I can use a regex that'd be much better.

Edit:
This is the code I have right now

```
`if (txtSearch.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        if (txtSearch.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
                        {
                            dataSource = dataSource.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToLower().Trim())).ToList();
                        }
                    }`
```

Comment: It seems to me the question is not complete. `Contains` will exactly return the expected string when the keywords are provided. I am almost sure you do not need regex here (with current description).

Comment: @stribizhev yes, you are right, what I also should have added is that I don't want to search for "o" or "t" or "e" or "at" and get result back

Comment: These are just substring literals you are trying to find. If you need some ambiguity in the search, regex can give you that, but not needed for simple substring literals. However, regex blows away ordinary api's for mass find/replace of literals.

Comment: It seems like you want to just match complete words, correct?

Comment: Please post the code you have, and describe where it is not acting as expected. It sounds as if it were a kind of an autocompletion feature, with live autocompletion.

Comment: @DanielGimenez almost, like I'd want to be able to search "Bot" or "Wat" and get a result, I just don't want 1 or 2 chars that are contained within to make it show

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla Why not verify that the search string is more than 2 characters before searching then?

Comment: @juharr, yeah that's one way I was thinking, I was just hoping I could use regex and get it all in one go

Comment: Sometimes less is not more. Be sure to always write readable code you can comprehend after 6 months

Comment: @DarkBee something about premature optimization being evil...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is the `\b` word boundary anchor.

```
var searchString = "Bottle of Water";

var regex = new Regex(@"\bBottle of Water"); //or @"\bof", or @"\bWater", or @"\bof Water"
var match = regex.Match(searchString);
```

Then check `match.Success` to see if you have a match.

`\bWater` means match any case where "Water" is preceded by a word boundary (generally white-space, though possibly some other form of punctuation).

---

**EDIT:**

.Net regular expressions are by default case sensitive. If you want the regex to be case insensitive, you either supply [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx), or use the [`?i` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx). The `?i` option is useful if you only want certain parts to be case insensitive:

```
var searchString = "Bottle of Water";

var regex = new Regex(@"\bbottle of water", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //or @"\bof", or @"\bwater", or @"\bof water"
var regex2 = new Regex(@"(?i:\bBOTTLE of) Water"); //"Bottle of" is case-insensitive, "Water" is case sensitive.
var match = regex.Match(searchString);
var match2 = regex2.Match(searchString);
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the case listed in the question where if the search string is length of 1 he only wants to check if it starts with that.

Comment: Yes, it does. `\bo` will return true, because 'of' because with o. `\bt` will not, even though there's a 't' in water, because there's no word beginning with t.

Comment: From the way the question was worded it seemed he only wanted to check the start of a string not the individual words. If its the start of individual words your solution works great!

Comment: So I've combined this with an if that checks if length of string is less than 2 then it checks to see if that's what the whole name starts with and if it does it adds it to results. Now my question is, why doesn't the regex find "Yellow Post-it notes" when i search for "post-it"? @Shlomo

Comment: @Shlomo thanks for the edit but that is not what i meant but I see how you could have interpreted that way. I do a .ToLower to avoid case sensetivity, but that's a good tip thanks. My issue, I think has to do with the hyphen, the hypen inbetween post and it isn't letting me find it...

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. If the search string is 'Yellow Post-it notes' and I use case insensitivity, `\bit`, `\b-it`, `\bpost` and `\bpost-it` all work for me.

Comment: @shlomo, weird I'll take a look again but it wasn't working before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what you want your search to look like. Right now you have requirements that can't be solved in just one search (at least as far as I can tell). If the user enters one letter you only want to check if that the strings start with that letter. If there is more than one character you want to search the whole string for that word.

If this is the behavior you want you have to check the search string length and do the corresponding query for the search string length. Doing it this way has the added benefit of being explicit and easy to read.